# What is the value of ∑k=16(sin2πk/7−icos2πk/7)=?

Tags: complex-numbers

https://rankerer.com/question/mathematics/1GL6DbxIntWa/the-value-of-displaystyle-sum-k-1-6-bigg-sin-frac-2-pi-k-7-i-cos-frac-2-pi-k-7-bigg-is

this is the link of the question.please analyse it properly.TIA.

Comment: The sum that appears in the **edited question** is pretty different from the one in the link that was there...

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

That sum is, *apparently*,  just

$$\sum_{k=1}^6\left( e^{-2\pi i/7}\right)^k ....\text{the sum of some elements of a geometric sequence}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{7})-i\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{7})$$
Taking out $-i$ we get:
$$-i\bigg[\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{7})+i\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{7})\bigg]$$
Thus our sum becomes:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{6}{\bigg[-ie^{\frac{2k\pi i}{7}}}\bigg]=-i\bigg[\sum_{k=1}^{6}\big[e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{7}}\big]\bigg]$$
$$=-i\bigg[e^{\frac{2\pi i}{7}}+e^{\frac{4\pi i}{7}}+e^{\frac{6\pi i}{7}}+e^{\frac{8\pi i}{7}}+e^{\frac{10\pi i}{7}}+e^{\frac{12\pi i}{7}}\bigg]$$